I need to auto accept the nuget installation
param (
[switch]$ResetDistributionFolder,
[switch]$ListOnly,
[switch]$MicrosoftUpdate,
[switch]$NoAutoReboot,
[switch]$RebootAtMidnight,
[switch]$SkipModuleUpdate,
[switch]$SkipDrivers,
[switch]$SkipFirmware
)

if ($ResetDistributionFolder) {
Write-Host 'Stopping services...'
Stop-Service 'Windows Update' -Force
Stop-Service cryptSvc -Force
Stop-Service DoSvc -Force
Stop-Service bits -Force
Stop-Service msiserver -Force

    Write-Host 'Removing SoftwareDistribution folder...'
    Remove-Item 'C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\' -Force -Recurse
    Write-Host 'Removing CatRoot2 folder...'
    Remove-Item 'C:\Windows\System32\catroot2\' -Force -Recurse
    
    Write-Host 'Starting services...'
    Start-Service cryptSvc
    Start-Service 'Windows Update'

}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

if (-not (Get-PackageProvider -Name 'NuGet')) {
Write-Host 'Installing NuGet...'
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet  -Confirm:$false
}

if (-not (Get-InstalledModule -Name 'PSWindowsUpdate')) {
Write-Host 'Installing Windows Update PS module...'
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -MinimumVersion 2.2.0.2 -Force
} else {
if (!$SkipModuleUpdate) {
Write-Host 'Updating Windows Update PS module...'
Update-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate -Force
}
}

Write-Host 'Importing Windows Update PS module...'
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate -Force

$WUCommand = 'Get-WindowsUpdate'

if (!$ListOnly) {
$WUCommand = $WUCommand + ' -Install -AcceptAll'

    if ($RebootAtMidnight -and !$NoAutoReboot) {
        Write-Host 'Reboot at Midnight selected, setting Auto-Reboot on Finish to False.'
        $NoAutoReboot = $true

Exit
}

} else {
if ($RebootAtMidnight) {
Write-Host 'List Only selected.  No reboots will be performed.'
$RebootAtMidnight = $false

Exit
}
}

if ($MicrosoftUpdate) {
Write-Host 'We will be checking with Microsofts update servers directly.'
$WUCommand = $WUCommand + ' -MicrosoftUpdate'
} else {
Write-Host 'We will be checking with the update server indicated in Group Policies (ie: WSUS).'
}

if ($SkipDrivers) {
Write-Host 'We will not be including Drivers.'
$WUCommand = $WUCommand + ' -NotCategory "Drivers"'
} else {
Write-Host 'We will be including Drivers.'
if ($SkipFirmware) {
Write-Host 'We will not be including Firmware updates.'
$WUCommand = $WUCommand + ' -NotTitle "Firmware"'
} else {
Write-Host 'We will be including Firmware updates.'
}
}

Write-Host 'Starting Windows Update Check/Install...'
Write-Host ('-> Command used: "{0}"' -f $WUCommand)
Invoke-Expression $WUCommand

I've this powershell script to force the updates on windows
I've try every command to auto-accept the nuget installation.
I've try to use a auto insall script for the nuget but when i run this script keeps asking me to install the nuget.
But when I run, it alwasy ask me to approve the nuget installation, and i need a way to auto-accept the nuget
instalation as you can see the following image


I know it's not pertinent to your question, but what's the point of setting the value of $NoAutoReboot (or $RebootAtMidnight), only to exit immediately after?

It's just for testing the code in the first phase.
When i resolve the nuget issue i will to correct that part.

Gotcha. For the actual question: try filtering by the specific version that's required, eg. if(-not(Get-PackageProvider -Name NuGet |? Version -ge '2.8.5.201' ))

See all the options for Get-WindowUpdate (https://gist.github.com/cfebs/c9d83c2480a716f6d8571fb6cc80fd59)  You may need to use -AcceptAll.

Try Install-PackageProvider ... -Force as well as -Confirm:$false. I've also had a similar problem in the past in a corporate project that I can't unfortunately share the code from, but it might be Get-PackageProvider that is causing the prompt, not Install-PackageProvider - see https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/496#issuecomment-754406476. If you check the version of the PackageManagement module first and upgrade that if lower than version 1.4.7 (or just do an upgrade regardless since it skips if already at the desired version) it may fix the issue

I've done install-packageprovider nuget -force

Please try this code:
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force

It should remove the confirm message
Reegards!
